# AngularJS, activate checkboxes before ng-model is declared

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ajax, checkbox

I'm developing a web application using Angular and I need some checkboxes that are related to the contents of a db so I'm using ng-repeat for that. I want an auxiliary array to control the ng-model and initially all checkboxes must be true.

I get the data from an ajax request and I don't now in advance how many elements I'm going to get so I don't know how many checkboxes will be. The problem is that I don't know the size of the auxiliary array until the ajax call has finished and by that time the checkboxes have already appeared on the screen unchecked.

My code is the following:

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="c in categories">
    <label for="{{c.id}}" ><input type="checkbox" ng-model="catselection[c.id]">{{c.name}}</label>
</div>
```

And in the controller I have this:

```
$http.get("api.php/categories")
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        $scope.categories = data;
        $scope.catselection = [];
        for(x in $scope.categories){
            $scope.catselection.push("true");
        }
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {});
```

The rest of the behavior is correct but I need the checkboxes to be activated at the beginning, I've tried the html attribute *checked* and even *ng-checked* and I know is not recommended with ng-model and nothing seems to work so far.

Comment: Have you tried with window.onload event so that you can apply settings to checkbox once the document has finished loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)?

```
...
<label for="{{c.id}}" ><input type="checkbox" ng-model="catselection[c.id]" ng-init="catselection[c.id] = true">{{c.name}}</label>
...
```

Comment: It works perfectly! I can even remove the loop for populating the auxiliary array. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure of the direct fix for checkboxes, but I'd look into the `value=""` attribute of the `<input>` tag. When I've used `value=""` in my own project with radio inputs then it'd automatically select the correct radio-input whenever I changed the value of the `ng-model` I linked the radio inputs to. (project: http://omrin7.github.io/potg/. Note how `bgImg` is set to 'dva' and it automatically picks it.)

Comment: I see that it works for you but it doesn't seem to be working in my case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the response (data array) to your scope variable after you have created your auxiliary array ($scope.catselection).

```
$http.get("api.php/categories")
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){       
        $scope.catselection = [];
        for(x in $scope.categories){
            $scope.catselection.push("true");
        }
     $scope.categories = data;
    })
```

Also instead of using c.id use $index.

```
ng-model ="catselection[$index]"
```